# Mains into a relay?

Tags: relay, mains

Will hot/live go into NO and neutral into COM, to switch over 200v? Can someone explain please. I saw in some places it says natural into NO but what into com?

Comment: Depends. Are you trying to blow the fuse/breaker, or run electronic equipment?

Comment: Hell no - that'll cause an instant short circuit, melted wires, fires, and blown fuses.  Live goes into COM, and "switched live" comes out of NO - or the other way around, it doesn't matter. Neutral stays well away from the relay.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams pretty sure I'm trying to run a component.

Comment: Then your component has to be somewhere in the circuit.

Comment: It always worries the hell out of me when someone obviously lacking in basic electrical knowledge is messing around with mains.  Professionals exist so that novices don't kill themselves and all those around them with dodgy wiring.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle: If your answer won't get accepted, you know why ;) - joke aside, a lot of people seem to underestimate the danger of mains supply. They fear a small "outch that hurt" at most.

Answer (score 2):

A relay is just a switch - just like a light switch.  It interrupts or connects the connection of LIVE (or "hot") to your device. Neutral remains connected direct to your device at all times.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg8M96.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Should I put electrical tape over the NC part of the relay?

Comment: I don't know. What is your relay? How is it mounted? What connections are you using?

Comment: So far it's not mounted or connected cuz I didn't want to start a fire but I think I'll just put some tape i case.

Comment: Please post an image of your relay, and describe how you think you are going to attach the wires to it.

Comment: If you connect the COM terminal to hot/live, then one or the other terminal will always be live.  Which it is depends on whether the coil is powered or not.  If you like, you can use this to run a small light to tell you that the load is off.

Comment: Or connect it the other way around - live into NO and switched live from COM, so NC is never live.

Comment: Or, as Majenko said, you can connect the NO or NC terminal to hot/live and the COM terminal to the load, and then the other terminal is never live.  You can then connect that one to neutral to short the load when it's supposed to be off.  Whether that's useful or not depends on the load, but it may protect the relay somewhat by killing an internal arc.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle this is a picture of how im wiring Hot into the relay: http://i.imgur.com/xP8OiCC.jpg

Comment: Ok i tested it and it works thanx for you help everyone!